# How can I find the install data of the last security patch installed?

Tags: debian, rhel, security, date

I would like to find out in which date the last security patch was installed.

I use a Debian 7.0 server and a RedHat 7 server.

I tried on RedHat:

```
rpm -qa --last
```

I get package names and install / update dates but I cannot understand which are security and which are not.

Comment: Can You provide more detail information about security packages/security patches? When you did a update.It will fix some bugs for previous packages.When You paid RHEL.Sure, You will get security update from REDHAT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On RHEL, you can list all installed security updates using `yum`:

```
yum updateinfo list security installed
```

This lists the updates alphabetically, so to sort them based on their advisory number, you'd use:

```
yum updateinfo list security installed | sort
```

(See [Is it possible to limit yum so that it lists or installs only security updates?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021) for more info about the `yum` security plugin.)

However, that doesn't give you dates. If you're otherwise happy with the output of `rpm -qa --last`, you can correlate the two by some piping:

```
grep "$(yum updateinfo list security installed | \
tail -n +3 | head -n -1 | awk '{ print $3 }')" <(rpm -qa --last)
```

Basically, you're grepping for the package names from the above output of `yum` in the output of that `rpm` command. (The `tail` and `head` commands just help you get rid of unwanted output from `yum`.)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your input...
Sadly it doesn't add much to the command I already put into the question (rpm -qa --last)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- you wanted to filter out the security updates, which I believe has been achieved.

Comment: Oh that is perfectly right: I "just" missed the security part from your command :)

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to add to the question the solution I've found for Debian (doesn't filter on security but at least you get the last update date):

```
is_debian=$(cat /proc/version | grep -i Debian | wc -l) && if [ "$is_debian" -eq 1 ]; then last_update=$([ -s /var/log/dpkg.log ] && tail -n 1 /var/log/dpkg.log || tail -n 1 /var/log/dpkg.log.1 | awk '{ print $1 }' ) && echo $last_update; fi ;
```